# Dynamic adminLTE or Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, adminlte

I've been playing with this awesome admin template ([adminLTE](https://almsaeedstudio.com/preview)).
The template is based on [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and has a lot of cool features.
I'm new to Bootstrap and all the tutorials I found were with hard-coded HTML and not dynamic content.
I couldn't even find a basic js function to create dynamic table which supports adminLTE and Bootstrap.

My question is if there exist a bootstrap or adminLTE javascript class that creates dynamic elements?

I couldn't find any in [adminLTE docs](https://almsaeedstudio.com/preview) or [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know any that show dynamic information, if you want to do something like this you must write a bit of code, fill an array with the values that you will show in the graph or add content using the template already created, the templates serve as an example to create your own site with less effort.